# XLPagerTabStrip height bar

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xlpagertabstrip

[My result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiRsf.png)

I wanna customization bar height

[How can i do like this ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goxtD.png)

Comment: This question is liable to be put **on hold** because it is of very poor quality, that you didn't provide any relevant code, and therefore the questions is unclear and potentially too broad.

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip Docs:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     self.settings.style.selectedBarHeight = 5
     self.settings.style.selectedBarBackgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
     self.isProgressiveIndicator = true

     super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: What is the difference to my answer other than you add more information that is not relevant to the specific question?